# pass tkinter user inputs into document's table

Tags: python, tkinter

its my first contact in here. i am quite new in programming.

i write the below code.
i need to pass the users inputs to the table docx. but i kinda stuck.
THe problem is that the user can appear as many inputs wants. so i find difficult to use entry.get() to an entry which doesnt have variable to call. I tries to make the entry and combo to list and pass it to the table rows but doesnt seem to write it correctly. below you will find the last correct program of mine(before all tries and errors).

```
from docx import Document
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

w = Tk()
w.geometry('700x800')
w.config(bg='#DCDCDC')


def add_combo_r():
    combo_res = ttk.Combobox(w, value = options_res).pack()

def add_entry_r ():
    descr_res_text = Entry(w).pack()   

def generate():

    document = Document()

    table1 = document.add_table(rows=2, cols=1,style= 'Table Grid')
    hdr_cells = table1.rows[0].cells
    hdr_cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run('NUMBERS ').bold = True

    document.save('test.docx')

btn = Button(w,text='ganarate docx', command=generate).pack()

b_res = Button(w, text = "add next result", command= add_combo_r).pack()
b_res_text = Button(w, text= "add next result by myself", command = add_entry_r ).pack()

options_res = ["1", "2","11", "12","21", "22","31", "32","41", "42","51", "52"]
combo_res = ttk.Combobox(w, value = options_res).pack()
descr_res_text = Entry(w).pack()

w.mainloop()
```

i tried to get the below table as a result:

| NUMBERS |
| --- |
| 1(combo result) |
| stairs (entry result) |
| 12(combo result) |
| 22(combo result) |
| turbo(entry result) |

i appreciate any help!!!

Comment: _" i find difficult to use entry.get() to an entry which doesnt have variable to call"_ why aren't you creating a variable that you can call the `get` method on?

Comment: The thing is that user can createas as many combo_res and combo_res_text he wish with a button click. User may decide that wants 2, 5 inputs or 100 inputs. so i need the button to generate a new variable in each click that my new combos and entries will be linked with, then somehow i need to count the inputs and generate the table in correst rows.

Comment: Store the entry widgets in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I reply the answer in case someone else need it in the future. :)

```
from docx import Document
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

w = Tk()
w.geometry('700x800')
w.config(bg='#DCDCDC')

entries_1 = []
counte1 = 0 

def add_entry_r():
    global counte1 
    entries_1.append(Entry(w))
    entries_1[-1].grid(row=0,column=counte1,padx=5)
    counte1 += 1 

def add_combo_r():
    global counte1
    entries_1.append(ttk.Combobox(w, value = options_res))
    entries_1[-1].grid(row=0,column=counte1,padx=5)
    counte1 += 1 

def generate():

    document = Document()
    table1 = document.add_table(rows=counte1+1, cols=1,style= 'Table Grid')
    hdr_cells = table1.rows[0].cells
    hdr_cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run('NUMBERS ').bold = True
    k=0
    for i in range(len(entries_1)):
        x=entries_1[k].get()
        row_cells=  table1.rows[i+1].cells
        row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run(x)
        k+=1
    
    document.save('test.docx')

btn = Button(w,text='genarate docx', command=generate).grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5)

b_res = Button(w, text = "add next result", command= add_combo_r).grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5)

b_res_text = Button(w, text= "add next result by myself", command = add_entry_r ).grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5)
options_res = ["1", "2","11", "12","21", "22","31", "32","41", "42","51", "52"]


w.mainloop()
```